# Why does mongodb require three config servers

Tags: mongodb

The official mongodb documentation states to use three config servers. They say its for redudancy, because 1 server would be a point of failure.... but why not 2? in a production sharded cluster, if I have 1 shard, I shouldn't need more than 2, right? Is one config server only meant to handle 1 shard? so, if the minimum is 2 shards, then at least I should have 3?

Comment: I answered a similar question on StackOverflow: [Why mongodb config servers must be one or three only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232025/why-mongodb-config-servers-must-be-one-or-three-only).

Answer (score 5):

Config servers are a special case, you can use one (for testing), or three and that's it.  They are **not** a replica set, at least not yet, that might change in the future, see [SERVER-1448](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1448).

Go and (re)read the first two paragraphs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/) - note the piece about them not being a replica set is explicitly mentioned.  I will pick out some other relevant points:

> Config servers use a two-phase commit to ensure immediate consistency
> and reliability
>
> to ensure redundancy and safety in production, you should always use
> three

The first part gives you a hint about why 3 are needed, the second part is telling, particularly in terms of the safety aspect (redundancy is obvious - you have 3 copies of the data).

With how the 2 phase commit is implemented, all three config servers must receive (and acknowledge) a change for it to be considered successful.  That's the safety piece - all three must be in a quorum and have the same data (there are regular checks), and that is why it is three config servers required exactly (for now).  When you run with just one for testing, this can't happen, and your cluster meta data is essentially at risk, hence using just one is for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

The document does not say why we need 3 config servers. But it is recommended to use odd number of mongods in each shard, maybe for quick elect? I think it is the same reason why we need odd number of config servers. I am not sure.

Each config server can handle lots of shards. config server does not consume too much resource, such as disk. Because config server store config info, meta data, not the user data. So you can use one config server in your deployment for lots of shards. But in production, for redundancy, it is suggested to use 3 config servers. each config server has nearly the same data copy.

Comment: Is it recommended to use odd number of mongods in each shard?? I thought the minimum was two shards...

Comment: (1)Please see the doc http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/ It says that an odd number of members ensures that the replica set is always able to elect a primary. If you have an even number of members, add an arbiter to get an odd number. Arbiters do not store a copy of the data and require fewer resources. Each shard always should be a replication set in production for reliability. (2) In my production, I just have one shard now. But in the future, we may add new shard, depending on the data size.

Comment: That explains the odd number for the actual shards - but what about the config servers?

Comment: The odd number also doesn't make complete sense. If I have 3 members, and 1 dies, then I have only 2 left - wouldn't I get a tie between the two?

Comment: According to my experience, one more config server does not consume too much space.

Comment: (1)three members have the same fault tolerance with 4 members. (2) There are two cases when one primary should be elected. one case is the first time the mongo cluster is setup. The second case is that the primary become unavailable. In this case, the election is like http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/

Comment: I know it doesn't consume space, but what is the logic behind having 3 config servers, as opposed to 2??

Also, how does having 4 members have the same issue as 3? In the case of three members - if 1 dies, there is only 2 secondary left, which during an election, can have a tie...

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/

Answer (score 0):

Why it always 1 or more than 2? Obvious answer is **split brain** problem. Any instance or programs that falls under replication would face this issue. Read more [this](https://qbox.io/blog/split-brain-problem-elasticsearch)